# Is kettle a good data migration solution?

Tags: migration, kettle

Has anybody some experience with [Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.org/)?
I'm searching for a good data migration solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, kettle is good - but it does of course depend on exactly what you're doing.

If you're purely moving data from one db to another without changing it, you're best sticking with the database vendors own utilities.

Saying that kettle has wide support for bulk loaders, so it is good there.  It also has some very exciting cloud support now.

I've found kettle extremely flexible, and also found the support available on their open forums very good too.  They take no prisoners though!  We completed a very complicated integration project using kettle and only came across one bug of note, and this was easy to work around.

The last thing to note about Kettle is that they are extremely hot on performance, with very good logging and monitoring facilities.

I havent used any other open source migration tools, Talend is one worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Kettle is really good for data migration.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, Sagar.  Could you expand on this and provide some insight into the advantages of Kettle?  Perhaps some links to resources you have found valuable?  Cheers~